# Как сделать конструктор в С++, число аргументов которого зависит от параметра шаблона

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Я пишу класс вектор

```
template <typename T, unsigned char size>
class Vector
{
public:

    Vector()
    {

    }

private:
    T vector[size];
};
```

Я хочу сделать свои конструкторы для разных размеров вектора, которые будут принимать разное количество аргументов. Я уже пробовал наследовать вектора основных размеров (2, 3, 4) и делать для них свои конструкторы, но это приводило к ненужным проблемам связанным с различиями типов.

Comment: А зачем вам такие конструкторы? Я почти уверен, что можно обойтись и без них.

Comment: мне одному непонятно?..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<typename... x_Args>
Vector(x_Args &&... args): vector{::std::forward<x_Args>(args)...}
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(x_Args) == size);
}
```